# Find all matrices that they have eigenvalues from $N(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Find one matrix $A\in M_3,_4(\mathbb R)$ such that 
$N(A)=L((-3,1,0,0)(-2,0,-6,1))$
then decribe all that matrices.

We need to find solutin for $Ax=0$ where $x$ can show as linear combination of $(-3,1,0,0)$ and $(-2,0,-6,1)$

I find this matrices

> A=$\begin{bmatrix}
>     1& 3& 1& 8\\
>     0& 0& 1& 6\\
>     0& 0& 0& 0
>    \end{bmatrix}$.

but I need to decribe all matrices, this matrices look after some elementary transformation. But from here we can see that third row can show as linear combination of other two $A_{3\cdot}=\gamma A_{2\cdot}+\omega A_{1\cdot}$, $A_{2\cdot}=\begin{bmatrix}
    \alpha a& \beta b& e& f
   \end{bmatrix}$.
$A_{1\cdot}=\begin{bmatrix}
    a& b& c& d
   \end{bmatrix}$.

> A=$\begin{bmatrix}
>     a& b& c& d\\
>     \alpha a& \beta b& e& f\\
>     \gamma a+\alpha\omega a& \gamma b+\beta b& \gamma c+\omega e& \gamma d+\omega f
>    \end{bmatrix}$. $a\not=0$

something like that but I need yours opinion, what you think?

Comment: This doesn’t have anything to do with eigenvalues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the standard basis. Now find the unit vectors linearly independent of the given vectors say {$e\space, f$} .Since $\space N(A) =2$ then rank of $A$ is 2 by Dimension Theorem. Now By
Gram–Schmidt orthogonalization process find the basis of $N(A) ^\perp$

Comment: The rank of $A$ is 2, though. It will have 2 pivotal columns.

Comment: yes now i see that rank A=2 because this matrix can be of some linear operation $\mathbb R^4\to \mathbb R^3$

Comment: Yeah Sorry... MY Mistake

Comment: This doesn’t describe _all_ such matrices. For example, the matrix with rows $2e$, $0$, $2f$ also has the correct null space, but doesn’t fit your description in several ways. Also, you can’t just take *any* vectors that are not elements of $N(A)$: you need a basis for $N(A)^\perp$.

Comment: Your example also has 2 pivotal columns

Comment: But it doesn’t fit your criteria for the rows of $A$. More importantly, however, having two pivot columns only guarantees that $\dim N(A)=2$, not that $A$ has the correct null space. For example, $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$ meets all of your criteria, but quite obviously doesn’t have the correct null space.

Comment: That's why i chose two vectors from the standard basis which are linearly independent with the given vectors and then i showed that the rows of matrix $A$ will be either e or f or a linear combination of e and f......

Comment: That exactly describes my example matrix, yet it has the wrong null space. The key thing that you’re missing is that $e$ and $f$ can’t just be outside of $N(A)$. They have to be elements of $N(A)^\perp$.

Comment: Oh Damn! I missed the case $N(A) +N(A) ^\perp=R^{4}$

Answer (score 0):

The row space of a matrix is the orthogonal complement of its null space. Since $\dim N(A)=2$, the dimension of the row space is also $2$, therefore the matrices that satisfy the given conditions have two linearly-independent rows that span $N(A)^{\perp}$, with the remaining row a linear combination of the other two.

You’ve already found a basis for $N(A)^\perp$, so we can say that each row of $A$ must be a linear combination of $(1,3,1,8)$ and $(0,0,1,6)$, subject to the additional conditions described above.

Another way to characterize this set of matrices is that they are of the form $BA$, where $A$ is the matrix that you’ve already found and $B$ is any invertible $3\times3$ matrix. The rows of the product $BA$ are all linear combinations of the rows of $A$, and requiring that $B$ be invertible guarantees that the null space won’t change.